# Why can't I cast ContactBody to a custom SKNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, collision, contacts

I am having trouble trying to cast a ContactBody to a custom SKNode. The implementation looks like this:

```
    case PhysicsCategory.player | PhysicsCategory.spring:
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.spring{

            if let theSpring = contact.bodyA.node as? Spring
            {
                theSpring.printMsg()
            }else{
               print("can't cast bodyA to spring")
            }
        }else{
            if let theSpring = contact.bodyB.node as? Spring
            {
                theSpring.printMsg()
            }else{
                print("can't cast bodyB to spring")
            }
        }
```

When contact is made between the player and the spring, I get the message "can't cast bodyA to spring." The spring class looks like this:

```
import SpriteKit
class Spring: SKNode {

var impulse: Int
var sprite: SKSpriteNode
var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
init (launchSpeed: Int){
    impulse = launchSpeed
    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "NonTiledItems")
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: textureAtlas.textureNamed("spring01"))
    sprite.physicsBody =  SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.spring // could we make this button?
    sprite.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    sprite.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    sprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    sprite.physicsBody!.friction = 0.6
    sprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player
    super.init()
    addChild(sprite)
}

func printMsg(){
    print("contact Made")
}
}
```

I cannot figure out why the ContactBody will not cast to the Spring class since spring inherits from SKNode. If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your physics body is attached to an SKSpriteNode, not the Spring.  You need to remove the skspritenode reference,  you need Spring to be a child of SKSpriteNode, and you need to write a convenience init like this:

```
convenience init (launchSpeed: Int)    
{
    self.SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTextureAtlas(named: "NonTiledItems").textureNamed("spring01"))
    impulse = launchSpeed

    self.physicsBody =  SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.spring // could we make this button?
    self.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody!.friction = 0.6
    self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the SKSpriteNode attached so I can add an image to the object, but the physics body did not need to be part of the sprite, just the object itself. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: You are welcome, I am a little confused, I am adding the image,  but I did notice that i assigned texture atlas after, so I am editing my code to correct it